# Reserve Number Format from Original JSON Data

Tags: json, plsql, floating-point, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

I am using Oracle Apex 22.2 and Oracle Database XE 21c on CentOS7. I am traversing all the nested elements of JSON data with the procedure shown below. However when I get the value of a number, the number loses its original format. For example, instead of getting 100.0, I get 100. How can I reserve the original format of the number? As you can see in my code below, I am using to_String to get value of the number. This is was one of my attempts to reserve the original number format. I have also tried with TO_CHAR & TO_NUMBER() . All give the same output. Your help is really appreciated.

**Procedure Code**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE (
  json_in    IN     JSON_ELEMENT_T,
  can_str    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
  object_key IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
IS
BEGIN
  IF json_in.is_Object() THEN
    DECLARE
      l_object JSON_OBJECT_T := TREAT(json_in AS JSON_OBJECT_T);
      l_keys   JSON_KEY_LIST := l_object.get_Keys();
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. l_keys.COUNT LOOP
        can_str := can_str || '"'||UPPER(l_keys(i))||'"';
        ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE(l_object.get(l_keys(i)), can_str, l_keys(i));
      END LOOP;
    END;
  ELSIF json_in.is_Array() THEN
    DECLARE
      l_array JSON_ARRAY_T := TREAT(json_in AS JSON_ARRAY_T);
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 0 .. l_array.get_size - 1 LOOP
        IF object_key IS NOT NULL THEN
          can_str := can_str || '"'||UPPER(object_key)||'"';
        END IF;
        ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE(l_array.get(i), can_str);
      END LOOP;
    END;
  ELSIF json_in.is_Scalar() THEN
    IF json_in.is_String() THEN
        can_str := can_str || json_in.to_String();
    ELSIF json_in.is_Number() THEN
        can_str := can_str || '"' || TO_NUMBER(json_in.to_String) || '"';
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

**Sample Code -  PL/SQL Block**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
   can_str     VARCHAR2(32767);
   l_doc       CLOB := '{
    "issuer": {
        "address": {
            "branchID": "1",
            "country": "EG",
            "governate": "Cairo",
            "regionCity": "Nasr City",
            "street": "580 Clementina Key",
            "buildingNumber": "Bldg. 0",
            "postalCode": "68030",
            "floor": "1",
            "room": "123",
            "landmark": "7660 Melody Trail",
            "additionalInformation": "beside Townhall"
        },
        "type": "B",
        "id": "113317713",
        "name": "Issuer Company"
    },
    "receiver": {
        "address": {
            "country": "EG",
            "governate": "Egypt",
            "regionCity": "Mufazat al Ismlyah",
            "street": "580 Clementina Key",
            "buildingNumber": "Bldg. 0",
            "postalCode": "68030",
            "floor": "1",
            "room": "123",
            "landmark": "7660 Melody Trail",
            "additionalInformation": "beside Townhall"
        },
        "type": "B",
        "id": "313717919",
        "name": "Receiver"
    },
    "documentType": "I",
    "documentTypeVersion": "0.9",
    "dateTimeIssued": "2020-10-27T23:59:59Z",
    "taxpayerActivityCode": "4620",
    "internalID": "IID1",
    "purchaseOrderReference": "P-233-A6375",
    "purchaseOrderDescription": "purchase Order description",
    "salesOrderReference": "1231",
    "salesOrderDescription": "Sales Order description",
    "proformaInvoiceNumber": "SomeValue",
    "payment": {
        "bankName": "SomeValue",
        "bankAddress": "SomeValue",
        "bankAccountNo": "SomeValue",
        "bankAccountIBAN": "",
        "swiftCode": "",
        "terms": "SomeValue"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "approach": "SomeValue",
        "packaging": "SomeValue",
        "dateValidity": "2020-09-28T09:30:10Z",
        "exportPort": "SomeValue",
        "countryOfOrigin": "EG",
        "grossWeight": 10.50,
        "netWeight": 20.50,
        "terms": "SomeValue"
    },
    "invoiceLines": [
        {
            "description": "Computer1",
            "itemType": "GPC",
            "itemCode": "10001774",
            "unitType": "EA",
            "quantity": 5,
            "internalCode": "IC0",
            "salesTotal": 947.00,
            "total": 2969.89,
            "valueDifference": 7.00,
            "totalTaxableFees": 817.42,
            "netTotal": 880.71,
            "itemsDiscount": 5.00,
            "unitValue": {
                "currencySold": "EUR",
                "amountEGP": 189.40,
                "amountSold": 10.00,
                "currencyExchangeRate": 18.94
            },
            "discount": {
                "rate": 7,
                "amount": 66.29
            },
            "taxableItems": [
                {
                    "taxType": "T1",
                    "amount": 272.07,
                    "subType": "T1",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T2",
                    "amount": 208.22,
                    "subType": "T2",
                    "rate": 12
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T3",
                    "amount": 30.00,
                    "subType": "T3",
                    "rate": 0.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T4",
                    "amount": 43.79,
                    "subType": "T4",
                    "rate": 5.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T5",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T5",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T6",
                    "amount": 60.00,
                    "subType": "T6",
                    "rate": 0.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T7",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T7",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T8",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T8",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T9",
                    "amount": 105.69,
                    "subType": "T9",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T10",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T10",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T11",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T11",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T12",
                    "amount": 105.69,
                    "subType": "T12",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T13",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T13",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T14",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T14",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T15",
                    "amount": 105.69,
                    "subType": "T15",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T16",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T16",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T17",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T17",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T18",
                    "amount": 123.30,
                    "subType": "T18",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T19",
                    "amount": 105.69,
                    "subType": "T19",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T20",
                    "amount": 88.07,
                    "subType": "T20",
                    "rate": 10.00
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "description": "Computer2",
            "itemType": "GPC",
            "itemCode": "10003752",
            "unitType": "EA",
            "quantity": 7,
            "internalCode": "IC0",
            "salesTotal": 662.90,
            "total": 2226.61,
            "valueDifference": 6.00,
            "totalTaxableFees": 621.51,
            "netTotal": 652.90,
            "itemsDiscount": 9.00,
            "unitValue": {
                "currencySold": "EUR",
                "amountEGP": 94.70,
                "amountSold": 5.00,
                "currencyExchangeRate": 18.94
            },
            "discount": {
                "rate": 0,
                "amount": 10.00
            },
            "taxableItems": [
                {
                    "taxType": "T1",
                    "amount": 205.47,
                    "subType": "T1",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T2",
                    "amount": 157.25,
                    "subType": "T2",
                    "rate": 12
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T3",
                    "amount": 30.00,
                    "subType": "T3",
                    "rate": 0.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T4",
                    "amount": 32.20,
                    "subType": "T4",
                    "rate": 5.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T5",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T5",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T6",
                    "amount": 60.00,
                    "subType": "T6",
                    "rate": 0.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T7",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T7",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T8",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T8",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T9",
                    "amount": 78.35,
                    "subType": "T9",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T10",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T10",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T11",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T11",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T12",
                    "amount": 78.35,
                    "subType": "T12",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T13",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T13",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T14",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T14",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T15",
                    "amount": 78.35,
                    "subType": "T15",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T16",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T16",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T17",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T17",
                    "rate": 10.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T18",
                    "amount": 91.41,
                    "subType": "T18",
                    "rate": 14.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T19",
                    "amount": 78.35,
                    "subType": "T19",
                    "rate": 12.00
                },
                {
                    "taxType": "T20",
                    "amount": 65.29,
                    "subType": "T20",
                    "rate": 10.00
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "totalDiscountAmount": 76.29,
    "totalSalesAmount": 1609.90,
    "netAmount": 1533.61,
    "taxTotals": [
        {
            "taxType": "T1",
            "amount": 477.54
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T2",
            "amount": 365.47
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T3",
            "amount": 60.00
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T4",
            "amount": 75.99
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T5",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T6",
            "amount": 120.00
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T7",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T8",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T9",
            "amount": 184.04
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T10",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T11",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T12",
            "amount": 184.04
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T13",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T14",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T15",
            "amount": 184.04
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T16",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T17",
            "amount": 153.36
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T18",
            "amount": 214.71
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T19",
            "amount": 184.04
        },
        {
            "taxType": "T20",
            "amount": 153.36
        }
    ],
    "totalAmount": 5191.50,
    "extraDiscountAmount": 5.00,
    "totalItemsDiscountAmount": 14.00
}';

BEGIN 
   ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE(JSON_ELEMENT_T.parse( l_doc ), can_str);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(can_str);
END;
/
```

**Output**

```
"ISSUER""ADDRESS""BRANCHID""1""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""Cairo""REGIONCITY""Nasr City""STREET""580 Clementina Key""BUILDINGNUMBER""Bldg. 0""POSTALCODE""68030""FLOOR""1""ROOM""123""LANDMARK""7660 Melody Trail""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""beside Townhall""TYPE""B""ID""113317713""NAME""Issuer Company""RECEIVER""ADDRESS""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""Egypt""REGIONCITY""Mufazat al Ismlyah""STREET""580 Clementina Key""BUILDINGNUMBER""Bldg. 0""POSTALCODE""68030""FLOOR""1""ROOM""123""LANDMARK""7660 Melody Trail""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""beside Townhall""TYPE""B""ID""313717919""NAME""Receiver""DOCUMENTTYPE""I""DOCUMENTTYPEVERSION""0.9""DATETIMEISSUED""2020-10-27T23:59:59Z""TAXPAYERACTIVITYCODE""4620""INTERNALID""IID1""PURCHASEORDERREFERENCE""P-233-A6375""PURCHASEORDERDESCRIPTION""purchase Order description""SALESORDERREFERENCE""1231""SALESORDERDESCRIPTION""Sales Order description""PROFORMAINVOICENUMBER""SomeValue""PAYMENT""BANKNAME""SomeValue""BANKADDRESS""SomeValue""BANKACCOUNTNO""SomeValue""BANKACCOUNTIBAN""""SWIFTCODE""""TERMS""SomeValue""DELIVERY""APPROACH""SomeValue""PACKAGING""SomeValue""DATEVALIDITY""2020-09-28T09:30:10Z""EXPORTPORT""SomeValue""COUNTRYOFORIGIN""EG""GROSSWEIGHT""10.5""NETWEIGHT""20.5""TERMS""SomeValue""INVOICELINES""INVOICELINES""DESCRIPTION""Computer1""ITEMTYPE""GPC""ITEMCODE""10001774""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""5""INTERNALCODE""IC0""SALESTOTAL""947""TOTAL""2969.89""VALUEDIFFERENCE""7""TOTALTAXABLEFEES""817.42""NETTOTAL""880.71""ITEMSDISCOUNT""5""UNITVALUE""CURRENCYSOLD""EUR""AMOUNTEGP""189.4""AMOUNTSOLD""10""CURRENCYEXCHANGERATE""18.94""DISCOUNT""RATE""7""AMOUNT""66.29""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""272.07""SUBTYPE""T1""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T2""AMOUNT""208.22""SUBTYPE""T2""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T3""AMOUNT""30""SUBTYPE""T3""RATE""0""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T4""AMOUNT""43.79""SUBTYPE""T4""RATE""5""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T5""AMOUNT""123.3""SUBTYPE""T5""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T6""AMOUNT""60""SUBTYPE""T6""RATE""0""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T7""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T7""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T8""AMOUNT""123.3""SUBTYPE""T8""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T9""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T9""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T10""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T10""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T11""AMOUNT""123.3""SUBTYPE""T11""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T12""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T12""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T13""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T13""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T14""AMOUNT""123.3""SUBTYPE""T14""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T15""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T15""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T16""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T16""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T17""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T17""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T18""AMOUNT""123.3""SUBTYPE""T18""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T19""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T19""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T20""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T20""RATE""10""INVOICELINES""DESCRIPTION""Computer2""ITEMTYPE""GPC""ITEMCODE""10003752""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""7""INTERNALCODE""IC0""SALESTOTAL""662.9""TOTAL""2226.61""VALUEDIFFERENCE""6""TOTALTAXABLEFEES""621.51""NETTOTAL""652.9""ITEMSDISCOUNT""9""UNITVALUE""CURRENCYSOLD""EUR""AMOUNTEGP""94.7""AMOUNTSOLD""5""CURRENCYEXCHANGERATE""18.94""DISCOUNT""RATE""0""AMOUNT""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""205.47""SUBTYPE""T1""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T2""AMOUNT""157.25""SUBTYPE""T2""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T3""AMOUNT""30""SUBTYPE""T3""RATE""0""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T4""AMOUNT""32.2""SUBTYPE""T4""RATE""5""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T5""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T5""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T6""AMOUNT""60""SUBTYPE""T6""RATE""0""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T7""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T7""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T8""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T8""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T9""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T9""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T10""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T10""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T11""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T11""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T12""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T12""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T13""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T13""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T14""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T14""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T15""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T15""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T16""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T16""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T17""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T17""RATE""10""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T18""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T18""RATE""14""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T19""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T19""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T20""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T20""RATE""10""TOTALDISCOUNTAMOUNT""76.29""TOTALSALESAMOUNT""1609.9""NETAMOUNT""1533.61""TAXTOTALS""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""477.54""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T2""AMOUNT""365.47""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T3""AMOUNT""60""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T4""AMOUNT""75.99""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T5""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T6""AMOUNT""120""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T7""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T8""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T9""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T10""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T11""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T12""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T13""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T14""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T15""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T16""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T17""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T18""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T19""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T20""AMOUNT""153.36""TOTALAMOUNT""5191.5""EXTRADISCOUNTAMOUNT""5""TOTALITEMSDISCOUNTAMOUNT""14"
```

**Output Instances**
How to make it reserve the original number format?
So "EXTRADISCOUNTAMOUNT""5.00"`instead of`"EXTRADISCOUNTAMOUNT""5"`

OR

`"NETWEIGHT""20.50"` instead of `"NETWEIGHT""20.5"`

OR

`"TOTALITEMSDISCOUNTAMOUNT""14.00"` instead of `"TOTALITEMSDISCOUNTAMOUNT""14"`

OR

`"RATE""0.00"` instead of `"RATE""0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

Once you have parsed the JSON then Oracle has converted it to `JSON_ELEMENT_T` then there is no documented method that allows you to extract the underlying JSON text for that element so you can only use the [serialization methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/json-types.html#GUID-639D871E-D116-4793-888E-F7948E48F4DE):

> #### Serialization
>
> Serialization is the inverse of the parse function. The serialization operation takes the in-memory representation of the JSON data and prints it to a string. The serialization functions and procedures are:
>
> ```sql
> MEMBER FUNCTION to_String    RETURN VARCHAR2
> MEMBER FUNCTION to_Number    RETURN NUMBER
> MEMBER FUNCTION to_Date      RETURN DATE
> MEMBER FUNCTION to_Timestamp RETURN TIMESTAMP
> MEMBER FUNCTION to_Boolean   RETURN BOOLEAN
> MEMBER FUNCTION to_Clob      RETURN CLOB
> MEMBER FUNCTION to_Blob      RETURN BLOB
>
> MEMBER PROCEDURE to_Clob(c IN OUT CLOB)
> MEMBER PROCEDURE to_Blob(c IN OUT BLOB)
> ```

As noted in the documentation, "The serialization operation takes the in-memory representation of the JSON data and ...". Therefore if the parser converts the JSON to a `NUMBER` data type then only a `NUMBER` value will be stored and the formatting of the original JSON text is **NOT** stored. Since 10.00 is exactly the same value as 10 and a `NUMBER` does not store formatting then you can only retrieve the value 10 and not 10.00.

---

If you want to get the original text then you will have to use a different parser that lets you extract the underlying JSON text.

---

Alternatively, if all the numbers want to be formatted to 2 decimal places then you could use:

```sql
can_str := can_str || '"' || TO_CHAR(json_in.to_Number(), 'FM9999990D00') || '"';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5dogJAvv)

Comment: Unfortunately, not all number values in the JSON data have the same number of decimal places. Is there a certain JSON parser do you recommend for PL/SQL?

Comment: @kimoturbo No, I cannot recommend any. You can look at `JSON_DATAGUIDE` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BzhMV2tK) (but I don't think it will do what you want) or write your own (the JSON format is not complex) or, if Java is enabled in your database, you can try writing something in Java or finding an existing library.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
ELSIF json_in.is_Scalar() THEN
IF json_in.is_String() THEN
    can_str := can_str || json_in.to_String();
ELSIF json_in.is_Number() THEN
can_str := can_str ||'"'|| json_in.to_String()||'"';
END IF;
END IF;
```

Procedure:

```
`create or replace PROCEDURE ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE (
  json_in    IN     JSON_ELEMENT_T,
  can_str    IN OUT VARCHAR2,
  object_key IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
IS
BEGIN
  IF json_in.is_Object() THEN
    DECLARE
      l_object JSON_OBJECT_T := TREAT(json_in AS JSON_OBJECT_T);
      l_keys   JSON_KEY_LIST := l_object.get_Keys();
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 1 .. l_keys.COUNT LOOP
        can_str := can_str || '"'||UPPER(l_keys(i))||'"';
        ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE(l_object.get(l_keys(i)), can_str, 
l_keys(i));
      END LOOP;
    END;
  ELSIF json_in.is_Array() THEN
    DECLARE
      l_array JSON_ARRAY_T := TREAT(json_in AS JSON_ARRAY_T);
    BEGIN
      FOR i IN 0 .. l_array.get_size - 1 LOOP
        IF object_key IS NOT NULL THEN
          can_str := can_str || '"'||UPPER(object_key)||'"';
        END IF;
        ETA_JSON_SERIALIZE(l_array.get(i), can_str);
      END LOOP;
    END;
   
  ELSIF json_in.is_Scalar() THEN
    IF json_in.is_String() THEN
        can_str := can_str || json_in.to_String();
    ELSIF json_in.is_Number() THEN
    
      can_str := can_str ||'"'|| json_in.to_String()||'"';
    
END IF;
END IF;`
```

Output

```
"ISSUER""ADDRESS""BRANCHID""1""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""Cairo""REGIONCITY""Nasr City""STREET""580 Clementina Key""BUILDINGNUMBER""Bldg. 0""POSTALCODE""68030""FLOOR""1""ROOM""123""LANDMARK""7660 Melody Trail""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""beside Townhall""TYPE""B""ID""113317713""NAME""Issuer Company""RECEIVER""ADDRESS""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""Egypt""REGIONCITY""Mufazat al Ismlyah""STREET""580 Clementina Key""BUILDINGNUMBER""Bldg. 0""POSTALCODE""68030""FLOOR""1""ROOM""123""LANDMARK""7660 Melody Trail""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""beside Townhall""TYPE""B""ID""313717919""NAME""Receiver""DOCUMENTTYPE""I""DOCUMENTTYPEVERSION""0.9""DATETIMEISSUED""2020-10-27T23:59:59Z""TAXPAYERACTIVITYCODE""4620""INTERNALID""IID1""PURCHASEORDERREFERENCE""P-233-A6375""PURCHASEORDERDESCRIPTION""purchase Order description""SALESORDERREFERENCE""1231""SALESORDERDESCRIPTION""Sales Order description""PROFORMAINVOICENUMBER""SomeValue""PAYMENT""BANKNAME""SomeValue""BANKADDRESS""SomeValue""BANKACCOUNTNO""SomeValue""BANKACCOUNTIBAN""""SWIFTCODE""""TERMS""SomeValue""DELIVERY""APPROACH""SomeValue""PACKAGING""SomeValue""DATEVALIDITY""2020-09-28T09:30:10Z""EXPORTPORT""SomeValue""COUNTRYOFORIGIN""EG""GROSSWEIGHT""10.50""NETWEIGHT""20.50""TERMS""SomeValue""INVOICELINES""INVOICELINES""DESCRIPTION""Computer1""ITEMTYPE""GPC""ITEMCODE""10001774""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""5""INTERNALCODE""IC0""SALESTOTAL""947.00""TOTAL""2969.89""VALUEDIFFERENCE""7.00""TOTALTAXABLEFEES""817.42""NETTOTAL""880.71""ITEMSDISCOUNT""5.00""UNITVALUE""CURRENCYSOLD""EUR""AMOUNTEGP""189.40""AMOUNTSOLD""10.00""CURRENCYEXCHANGERATE""18.94""DISCOUNT""RATE""7""AMOUNT""66.29""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""272.07""SUBTYPE""T1""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T2""AMOUNT""208.22""SUBTYPE""T2""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T3""AMOUNT""30.00""SUBTYPE""T3""RATE""0.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T4""AMOUNT""43.79""SUBTYPE""T4""RATE""5.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T5""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T5""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T6""AMOUNT""60.00""SUBTYPE""T6""RATE""0.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T7""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T7""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T8""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T8""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T9""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T9""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T10""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T10""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T11""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T11""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T12""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T12""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T13""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T13""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T14""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T14""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T15""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T15""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T16""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T16""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T17""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T17""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T18""AMOUNT""123.30""SUBTYPE""T18""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T19""AMOUNT""105.69""SUBTYPE""T19""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T20""AMOUNT""88.07""SUBTYPE""T20""RATE""10.00""INVOICELINES""DESCRIPTION""Computer2""ITEMTYPE""GPC""ITEMCODE""10003752""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""7""INTERNALCODE""IC0""SALESTOTAL""662.90""TOTAL""2226.61""VALUEDIFFERENCE""6.00""TOTALTAXABLEFEES""621.51""NETTOTAL""652.90""ITEMSDISCOUNT""9.00""UNITVALUE""CURRENCYSOLD""EUR""AMOUNTEGP""94.70""AMOUNTSOLD""5.00""CURRENCYEXCHANGERATE""18.94""DISCOUNT""RATE""0""AMOUNT""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""205.47""SUBTYPE""T1""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T2""AMOUNT""157.25""SUBTYPE""T2""RATE""12""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T3""AMOUNT""30.00""SUBTYPE""T3""RATE""0.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T4""AMOUNT""32.20""SUBTYPE""T4""RATE""5.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T5""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T5""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T6""AMOUNT""60.00""SUBTYPE""T6""RATE""0.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T7""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T7""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T8""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T8""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T9""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T9""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T10""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T10""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T11""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T11""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T12""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T12""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T13""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T13""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T14""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T14""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T15""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T15""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T16""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T16""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T17""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T17""RATE""10.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T18""AMOUNT""91.41""SUBTYPE""T18""RATE""14.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T19""AMOUNT""78.35""SUBTYPE""T19""RATE""12.00""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T20""AMOUNT""65.29""SUBTYPE""T20""RATE""10.00""TOTALDISCOUNTAMOUNT""76.29""TOTALSALESAMOUNT""1609.90""NETAMOUNT""1533.61""TAXTOTALS""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""477.54""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T2""AMOUNT""365.47""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T3""AMOUNT""60.00""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T4""AMOUNT""75.99""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T5""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T6""AMOUNT""120.00""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T7""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T8""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T9""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T10""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T11""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T12""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T13""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T14""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T15""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T16""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T17""AMOUNT""153.36""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T18""AMOUNT""214.71""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T19""AMOUNT""184.04""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T20""AMOUNT""153.36""TOTALAMOUNT""5191.50""EXTRADISCOUNTAMOUNT""5.00""TOTALITEMSDISCOUNTAMOUNT""14.00"
```

Comment: Yes, I did. But it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I edited the replay with the canonical string, whats your issue with it ?

Comment: How did you get that output? I tried your way, but I still got the number without the same decimal places as in the original JSON file. For example, I got 

"EXTRADISCOUNTAMOUNT""5""TOTALITEMSDISCOUNTAMOUNT""14"

Instead of

EXTRADISCOUNTAMOUNT""5.00""TOTALITEMSDISCOUNTAMOUNT""14.00"

Comment: Updated the reply with the procedure,
ELSIF json_in.is_Number() THEN
 can_str := can_str ||'"'|| json_in.to_String()||'"';
This should preserve the numbers format !

Comment: I have copy and pasted the entire procedure from you and compiled it again and ran a test, but still that didn't solve the issue. How did you get the output?

Comment: I got it from this procedure , try storing ur json in clob column in the DB instead of passing it in the code, don't know if this makes any difference, but that's what I did.

Comment: I don't understand how saving the JSON data in a clob column in the DB differs from saving it in a CLOB variable.

Comment: most probably it doesn't !
i am just trying to explain how i exactly got that output using the same code that didn't work for you.